# Compiler warning (codeblocks/wxwidget): Your compiler does not appear to support 64 bit integers, using emulation class instead

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have been breaking my head over this - googling gets me no where, all I get is links to the actual header file inside which the warning message resides, the longlong.h

The error occurs after this line in longlong.h:

```
    #ifdef __GNUC__
```

IDE is codeblocks, wxWidgets version 3.0, Windows7 32 bit (I have compiled same code in my office PC, same setup).

Any idea what is the source of the error?

Comment: I should mention that this is the second time I'm getting this - previously I had the same problem in wxWidget 2.8, but managed to solve it by trial and error; now I forgot the solution!

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others (and myself for not having to do this the third time), the answer is - compiler search directory.
I had erroneously added "\CodeBlocks\WxWidget\include\wx" in addition to "\CodeBlocks\WxWidget\include". Removing the "\wx" folder did the trick!